# Make richtextbox single line only

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

Is it possible to make a richtextbox only able to contain one line? I want it to have the wraptext ability but I can't have multiple lines in the file it will generate.

Comment: Does setting the [RichTextBox.Multiline Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.multiline(v=vs.110).aspx) to False not work for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set its AcceptsReturn attribute to false that should only allow one line because it won't let the text return.

If for some reason your properties window doesn't have the AcceptsReturn property, you can add `if e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then e.SuppressKeyPress = True` under the event `KeyDown` (as suggested by [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi)).

Comment: I'm unable to find an AcceptsReturn property for RichTextBox elements in code or properties editor... Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @BrendenMcFarling, you say "elements". Does that mean that this is WPF? Please make sure to always add all relevant tags. People are almost always going to assume Windows Forms unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: @Brenden McFarling Well, you can intercept a KeyDown event and `if e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then e.SuppressKeyPress = True`. Or you can modify the RichTextBox Style [Rich Edit Control Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774367(v=vs.85).aspx) (ES_WANTRETURN) to have the same effect as `AcceptsReturn = False`. Or create an extension method using one of these options.

Comment: I did assume this was WCF. Should be able to set it as I said?

Comment: @jmcilhinney sorry, I guess I forgot "elements" refers to something specific, I'm just used to saying it in deference to, erm, items in general. It is a Windows Form project.

Comment: I'm going to try implementing @Jimi 's idea.

Comment: @scath It is WCF, just for some reason I don't have that property in the properties toolbox. Using VB.net 2010 Express.

Answer (score 0):

Simply think first,how do we get to the next line ? By pressing `Return` or `Enter`.So,in the `KeyPress` event of the `RichTextbox` you can simply use :

```
 If e.KeyChar = Keys.Return Then
    e.Handled = True
 End if
```

Now this has a major drawback and that is : What if a user copy pastes a multi-line text into the `richtextbox` ?

To fix that, you can simply apply the following code in the `TextChanged` event :

```
 Private Sub Rtb_TextChanged()
  Dim lcount as Integer = rtb.Lines.Count
  Dim i As Integer
  If lcount > 1 Then 
    For i = 2 to lcount - 1
     Dim index As Integer = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i)
     Dim count As Integer = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i + 1) - start_index
     rtb.Text = rtb.Text.Remove(index, count)
    Next
   End if
  End Sub
```

Hope this helps :)